# Multiple frames in a single tab ttk.Notebook

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

I have the following sections of code (not complete) where I would like to contain several frames into a single tab in the ttk 'Notebook'   .

```
win1 = Tk()    
n = ttk.Notebook(win1)

choice_frame = ttk.Frame(n, style="Black.TLabel")
choice_frame.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="N,S,E,W", padx=1, pady=1)
choice_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
choice_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame_text = ttk.Frame(n, style="Black.TLabel")
frame_text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "N")
frame_text.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
frame_text.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame_table = ttk.Frame(n, style="Black.TLabel")
frame_table.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=1, pady=1, sticky= " N, S, E, W ")
frame_table.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
frame_table.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

n.add(frame_table, text="One") # Would like same tab not two separate ones
n.add(choice_frame, text="One")
n.grid(sticky="N")
```

I would also like to know if there's a way of allowing every dimension to adjust automatically when the window is dragged out and maximised. I have previously tried:

```
frame_table.grid_propagate(0)
```

But this doesn't seem to allow the height as well as width dimension to stick. I would like my 'table' to be in the center of the window but adjust with the window size.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "be in the center .. but adjust with the window size". Those seem contradictory -- do you want it in the center, or do you want it to fill the frame?

Comment: I would like ideally for all of my widgets to be centered in the table with a slight border area around so the window isn't completely packed. I then however would like the whole thing to adjust it's size when the window is expanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grid_propagate` isn't a solution to any of your problems.

Each tab can contain only a single frame, but that single frame can contain whatever you want. So, create one container frame for the tab and then put all your other frames in the container frame. This is one of the main reasons the `Frame` class exists -- to build widget containers that facilitate layout.

As for the resizing, the problem is probably that you're not adding a weight to the rows and columns of the main window. Though it could also be related to the fact you are using `grid` to place the frames in the notebook; you can't use `grid` to place items in a notebook.

Comment: How would I create one Frame and add my other frames to it? I didn't know I could do that (I'm a complete beginner to this) and I've read some of your comments with grid and pack but I still don't understand how you can use both of them without conflicting. Very VERY simple explanations are needed here, I apologise in advance but thank you so much for you help!

Comment: I tried creating root = Tk() and then win1 = Frame(root), win1.grid() but it doesn't work and I get nothing at all.