# Tkinter - how to create a tab and move content to it?

Tags: python, tkinter

Created an application. I'd like to expand it, by adding multiple tabs.

Giving them names such as 'Main- Screen', 'Manual'. I'd be able to switch between the tabs, but I am not sure how to use, apply and structure my code by using `Notebook`.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class App():
    def __init__(self,master):
        #Frames
        left_frame = Frame(master)
        right_frame = Frame(master)
        left_frame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        right_frame.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

        var1 = IntVar()
        var1a = IntVar()

        #Displaying checkboxes and assigning to variables
        self.Checkbox = Checkbutton(right_frame, text="Ingredients present in full (any allergens in bold with allergen warning if necessary)", variable=var1)
        self.Checkbox.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = W)
        self.Checkbox2 = Checkbutton(right_frame, variable = var1a)
        self.Checkbox2.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = W)

       ###FRAME 2###
        #widgets
        self.msg1 = Label(left_frame, text = "Choose here")
        self.msg1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

root = Tk()
root.minsize(890, 400)
root.title("test only")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

How can I create a tab for the above and call it `Main-Screen` and also add the following code to a new tab and call it `Manual`:

```
    #widgets
    self.msg1 = Label(left_frame, text = "Click here!")
    self.msg1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
```

**Main question:**

How can I put the first piece of code into one tab and the other code into another tab? And be able to switch between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ttk.Frame:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageGrab
from pathlib import Path

class App():
    def __init__(self,master):
        notebook = ttk.Notebook(master)
        notebook.pack()

        #Frames
        left_frame = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        right_frame = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        notebook.add(left_frame, text='Main-Screen')
        notebook.add(right_frame, text='Manual')

        var1 = IntVar()
        var1a = IntVar()

        #Displaying checkboxes and assigning to variables
        self.Checkbox = Checkbutton(right_frame, text="Ingredients present in full (any allergens in bold with allergen warning if necessary)", variable=var1)
        self.Checkbox.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = W)
        self.Checkbox2 = Checkbutton(right_frame, variable = var1a)
        self.Checkbox2.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = W)

       ###FRAME 2###
        #widgets
        self.msg1 = Label(left_frame, text = "Choose here")
        self.msg1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

root = Tk()
root.minsize(890, 400)
root.title("test only")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, originally I need the left frame and right frame to be on the same screen, and another tab to be another frame

Comment: Maybe this is You looking for? Multiple frames in a single tab ttk.Notebook [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227388/multiple-frames-in-a-single-tab-ttk-notebook)

Comment: right and left frame are in same tab in `Main-screen`

Answer (score 0):

The `Notebook` provides you with a tabbed screen. A general example is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
note = ttk.Notebook(root)

ms = ttk.Frame(note)
note.add(ms, text = "Main-Screen")
mn = ttk.Frame(note)
note.add(mn, text = "Manual")
note.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Add your widgets as needed to frames `ms` and `mn`

Answer (score 0):

This how to add `notebook` to your main window, you can read more about it from this [link](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tkinter.Notebook). Have commented my code for to understand it better.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class App():
    def __init__(self,master):
        #Frames
        # Make the notebook
        nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
        nb.pack()

        # Make 1st tab
        right_frame = Frame(nb,)
        # Add the tab
        nb.add(right_frame, text="First tab")

        # Make 2nd tab
        left_frame = Frame(nb)
        # Add 2nd tab
        nb.add(left_frame, text="Second tab")

        nb.select(left_frame)

        nb.enable_traversal()

        var1 = IntVar()
        var1a = IntVar()

        #Displaying checkboxes and assigning to variables
        self.Checkbox = Checkbutton(right_frame, text="Ingredients present in full (any allergens in bold with allergen warning if necessary)", variable=var1)
        self.Checkbox.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = W)
        self.Checkbox2 = Checkbutton(right_frame, variable = var1a)
        self.Checkbox2.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = W)

       ###FRAME 2###
        #widgets
        self.msg1 = Label(left_frame, text = "Choose here")
        self.msg1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)


        # THIS IS THE THIRD FRAME
        self.bottomframe = Frame(master, bg="red", width=400, height=200)
        self.bottomframe.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)

        self.label3 = Label(self.bottomframe, text="THIS IS THE THIRD FRAME")
        # self.label3.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.label3.pack()            


root = Tk()
root.minsize(890, 400)
root.title("test only")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Lets say I created another class.. would alot of code needing to be changed?

Comment: No .. You have to place the `widget` in the frame you want inside the tab.

Comment: one more if you don't mind. If i create a new frame in my code.. how would I combine frame 1 and frame 2 as together and new frame as separate? I didn't explain my question properly. The two frames were separated to structure the layout for the the first screen. The code at the bottom (from the question) was the one I wanted to add into the new tab.